# Как настроить кнопки под ориентацию и расширения экрана Unity?

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

В этой игре, что на скринах все работает безупречно, кнопки автоматически подстраиваются под ориентацию и разные расширения экрана. Как можно также сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете [использовать якоря](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html) для привязки кнопок к определенному положению. Либо при запуске сцены рассчитывайте ширину и высоту экрана [(Screen.width и Screen.height)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html) и ставите кнопки в [нужном месте нужного размера](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html).
[Вот тут ещё почитайте про GUI](http://websketches.ru/blog/uhebnik-po-novomu-gui-v-unity-1)

Comment: одними якорями здесь не обойтись