# Как сохранить пропорции кнопок по изменению разрешения экрана GUI в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui

проблема такая, когда разрешение экрана меняется, меню уменьшается, как сохранить пропорции кнопок?

***Скрипт Меню:***

```
public class MenuScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float Screen_H, Screen_W, Screen_H_New, Screen_W_New, K_H, K_W, Center_W;
public GUISkin Skin;
public int Screen_1, Lang;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Screen_H = 480;
    Screen_W = 320;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //Screen_H_New = Screen.height;
    //Screen_W_New = Screen.width;
    //K_H = Screen_H_New / Screen_H;
    //K_W = Screen_W_New / Screen_W;
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width/2)-100,(Screen.height/2)-100,200,250), "Loader Menu");
    GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect((Screen.width/2)-75, (Screen.height/2)-75 , 200,200));

    GUI.skin = Skin;


    if(Screen_1==0 && Lang==0)
    {
        GUI.Button (new Rect(0,0,150,60), "PLAY");
        GUI.Button (new Rect(0,70,150,60), "OPTIONS");
        GUI.Button (new Rect(0,140,150,60), "QUIT");
    }
    GUI.EndGroup ();
}
}
```

**UPD:**

Если создавать стандартными средствами меню, использовать скрипт `Vertical Layout Group` 2:3 - работает нормально, 3:2 - почему-то меню не помещается. Как исправить ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*кнопки должны уменьшаться*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: всё [продолжение этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/807703/213987) вопроса? Нельзя как-то задаться на несколько типовых разрешений экрана и подготовить несколько раскладок? Вот в bootstrap для веб-приложений выбраны xs, sm, md, lg раскладки в качестве основных, по идее можно и себе аналогичный подход взять на вооружение.

Comment: я думаю можно как-то попроще) возможно у кого-то есть готовое решения, хотя бы в качестве примера привести

Comment: Вы ведь это для тестов, да? Вы ведь в релиз не выпустите игру с гуятиной на базе `GUI`?

Comment: А чем вас не устраивают решения на базе текущей версии интерфейса от Unity? Где требуемое вам легко настраивается прямо в инспекторе?

Comment: к сожалению оно там не работает нужным образом :(

Comment: добавил дополнительную информацию

Comment: @KillNoise, возможно, вы просто не умеете правильно настраивать? Я не вижу для вас иных решений, кроме ручного расчёта скейла исходя из текущего разрешения. В UI система для этого уже написаны нативные компоненты

Answer (score 1):

Используй canvas
Всё также можно настроить на canvas(другие текстурки там шрифт и тд) заодно можно конпки закрепить на определенном месте экрана. Плюс меньше кода
https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html